# Weird dialog box says Error: success ..?

Tags: samba, dialog

What can cause this strange error dialog to pop up?  The message just says 'success'.  I was trying to copy a file from my desktop to my laptop over smb protocol, and the file does seems to have copied successfully, so I'm not sure why it give an error dialog?!

[image]

Comment: What permissions on smb://wim-desktop/upload are you seeing?

How is the "upload" share defined on wim-desktop?